# Ruby gem for OAuth using EventMachine?

Tags: ruby, oauth

I am trying to use em-http-request with OAuth. It seems [em-http-oauth-request](https://github.com/draconis/em-http-oauth-request) is very outdated.

Does anyone know a simple way of doing an async OAuth request?